# Changing the constraints in a Container object

Tags: layout, java-8, containers

In Java 8, the *Container* class has an *void add(Component comp, Object constraints)* method that adds the component with a constraints information. I want to build a GUI with three panels, where pressing a button would result in switching the constraint information of the components that do not include the button object. How is it possible to switch the constraint information?

**EDIT:**
I tried the following:

```
    private Map<SpecUITitlePanel, GridBagConstraints> constraints = new Hashtable<SpecUITitlePanel, GridBagConstraints>();
    […]
        switchPanelsButton.setText( "Switch panels");
        switchPanelsButton.addActionListener( new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed( final java.awt.event.ActionEvent event) {
            switchPanelsActionPerformed( event);
          }
    […]

    private void switchPanelsActionPerformed( final java.awt.event.ActionEvent event) {
      boolean swapped = false;
      final GridBagLayout layout = (GridBagLayout) getLayout();
      final Iterator<SpecUITitlePanel> keysIter = constraints.keySet().iterator();
      // summaryPanel, testPanel

      while (keysIter.hasNext() && layout != null) {
        final SpecUITitlePanel key = keysIter.next();

        final String title = key.getTitle();
        final Iterator<SpecUITitlePanel> keysIter2 = constraints.keySet().iterator();

        while (keysIter2.hasNext()) {
          final SpecUITitlePanel key2 = keysIter2.next();

          final String title2 = key2.getTitle();

          if (!title.equals( title2)) {
            if (!title.contains( BUTTON_PANEL_TITLE) && !title2.contains( BUTTON_PANEL_TITLE)) {
              // swap components
              String message = "component = " + title + ", "
                + constraints.get( key) + "; component2 = " + title2
                + ", " + constraints.get( key2);

              System.out.println( message);
              final GridBagConstraints value = constraints.get( key);
              final GridBagConstraints value2 = constraints.get( key2);

              constraints.put(key, value2);
              layout.setConstraints( key, value2);
              constraints.put(key2, value);
              layout.setConstraints( key2, value);
              swapped = true;
              message = "component = " + title + ", "
                + constraints.get( key) + "; component2 = " + title2
                + ", " + constraints.get( key2);

              System.out.println( message);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if (swapped) {
      repaint();
    }
  }
```

The relevant part of the output is

```
component = Test, java.awt.GridBagConstraints@5179288b; component2 = tna.rads.main_panel.violation_summary_panel, java.awt.GridBagConstraints@f1a7ed2
component = Test, java.awt.GridBagConstraints@f1a7ed2; component2 = tna.rads.main_panel.violation_summary_panel, java.awt.GridBagConstraints@5179288b
```

Comment: This depends on the actual [`LayoutManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/awt/LayoutManager2.html) you are using. For some of them, it’s impossible (besides the option to remove and re-add the component). Others have special methods, e.g. [`GridBagLayout.setConstraints(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html#setConstraints-java.awt.Component-java.awt.GridBagConstraints-).

Comment: Thank you very much for the informative answer. I do not think that it's a good idea to remove all (up to a dozent) objects from the `LayoutManager`. I'll see tomorrow how to proceed.

Comment: I added code above, showing what I have done. Although `repaint()` is called, and the elements are swapped, the panel remains the same. Can you see the error?

Comment: The container doesn’t know that the layout has changed. So for a Swing component you should call `revalidate()` before `repaint()`, for non-Swing AWT you would have to call the sequence `invalidate(); validate(); repaint();`. By the way, why aren’t you using `for` loops like `for(SpecUITitlePanel key: constraints.keySet()) { … }` and `for(SpecUITitlePanel key2: constraints.keySet()) { … }`?

Comment: Thank you! I have some trouble, but will see that the refresh works. Yes, the four loops I used above are ugly.

Comment: How is it possible to get the component-layout tuples out of the `GridBagLayout`? Actually, it is possible to save it in a `Hashtable`, but as the layout information is added inside the generated `initComponents` method of Matisse, it is not a good idea to add some lines to it. So, I think about a way of getting the information out through the layout manager itself, as it was added by the `add(Component, Object)` method. How is this possible?

Comment: [`GridBagLayout.getConstraints(Component)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html#getConstraints-java.awt.Component-); it’s generally preferable to ask the layout for the actual constraint instead of remembering the object use while `add`ing, as the objects are mutable, so the constraint used for adding could have been modified and reused afterwards. `getConstraints` returns the state as being stored in the layout (a copy).

Comment: Your answers, especially the last one solved my problem. Thank you very much!